# How to pass values from App.vue to main.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am currently trying to implement localisation in vue js. The following is my code in `main.js`.

```
var lang = localStorage.getItem('locale') ? localStorage.getItem('locale') : '';
if (lang === '') {
    lang = 'en';
    localStorage.setItem('locale', lang);
}
```

There will be two flag images on the `App.vue` page. Whenever I click on the flags, a function `changeLocale()` is triggered. This is written in `App.vue`

```
methods : {
        changeLocale : function(ln){
          console.log(ln);
        }
    },
```

Now, from `App.vue` I need to change the value of the variable `lan` in `main.js`

Can someone help me to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you handle it all in App.vue? And leave only imports and instantiation to main.js. I assume App.vue is a root vue component.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on what you have in your main.js.
If you don't have your vue instance there, one idea would be to use an event bus.

In a third file, 'bus.js':

```js
const bus = new Vue();
module.exports = bus;
```

In App.vue:

```js
const bus = require('./bus.js');

// in methods:
changeLocale : function(ln) {
    bus.$emit('localeChanged', ln);
}
```

In main.js:

```js
const bus = require('./bus.js');
bus.$on('localeChanged', (locale) => {
    console.log('locale has changed, and its ' + locale);
});
```

See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting an error message like `Uncaught TypeError: bus.$on is not a function`. Instead of communicate two components, I want to implement a communication from `App.vue` to `main.js`

Comment: It doesn't matter if this is two components or anything else. The bus is the only thing important there. Can you console.log the bus?

Comment: How can i write `module.exports = bus;` using `export default` ? The former part is not working for me. Sorry to ask you this; I am really a newbie to node and vue js

Comment: Well it should work: 
`const bus = new Vue();
export default bus;`

---->

`import bus from './bus.js';`